# Group by SQL with count

Tags: sql

Lets say we have got rows like that:

MyTable

```
ID Name  Product
------------------
1  Adam  x
2  Adam  y
3  Adam  z
4  Peter a
5  Peter b
```

Using query like:

```
Select Name, Count(Product) from MyTable
group by Name
```

results will be:

```
Adam 3
Peter 2
```

But I would like results like:

```
1 Adam x 3
2 Adam y 3
3 Adam z 3
4 Peter a 2
5 Peter b 2
```

I hope Ypu know what I mean
Could You help me with that query,
thanks for help,
Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the table with a subquery run on the table to select the counts:

```
SELECT a.ID as ID, a.Name as Name, a.Product as Product, ISNULL(b.cnt,0) as Cnt
FROM MyTable a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as Cnt FROM MyTable GROUP BY Name) b
ON a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: ISNULL is only supported on SQL Server; on MySQL it'd be IFNULL -- neither of which are supported by Oracle...

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
Select *, Count() OVER(PARTITION BY Name) As C
from MyTable
```

Comment: Note that this syntax only works on certain SQL servers. MySQL, for instance, does not support `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Actually, it's the OVER clause MySQL doesn't support. MySQL doesn't support any analytical/windowing functionality currently.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.Id, 
       a.Name, 
       a.Product, 
       IsNull(b.CountOfUsers,0) as CountOfUsers

From MyTable a
Left Join (Select Name, Count(Product) as CountOfUsers from MyTable
          group by Name)b on a.Name = b.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH c AS (SELECT Name, COUNT(Product) CountOfProduct
            FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY Name)
SELECT t.Id, t.Name, t.Product, c.CountOfProduct
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN c ON c.Name = t.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.id, 
          x.name, 
          x.product, 
          COALESCE(y.name_count, 0) AS num_instances
     FROM MyTable x
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.name, 
                  COUNT(*) AS name_count
             FROM MyTable t 
         GROUP BY t.name) y ON y.name = x.name
```

COALESCE is the ANSI standard means of handling NULL values, and is supported by MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgre, etc.

Comment: The problem with a JOIN (or a correlated query) solution to this task is that, under a regaular/relaxed isolation level in a heavy INSERT/DELETE scenario, the returned count of items (num_instances) can be different from the actual count of rows returned per group. The LEFT JOIN and COALESCE try to reduce the effects of a problem that is introduced by a very simplistic solution. I recommend solving this problem with a windowing function over LEFT JOIN whenever available.